# (Vue.js) Importing values from one component to another, not sure if it can be done with props

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to learn vue and hit a small roadbump - is there a way for me to make this work? I want to push a new value into my items array with my Button component so then i can render it with the v-for. I know it would much be easier to put everything into one file, just curious if it can be done this way. Here is the code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-antonelli-7o6m6o?file=/src/App.vue

any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: You can pass anything down with props! You can also send data up by emitting it :) Data can go both ways. In your example, itemlist should have the prop 'items'.

Comment: So inside ItemList.vue i should put defineProps({ items: X})? What should be inside X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure this can be done the way you would like. One way to do it is to define the variables and the add function in the App.vue.

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";

const name = ref("");
const amount = ref(0);
const items = ref([]);

const addItem = () => {
  items.value.push = { name: name.value, amount: amount.value };
  name.value = "";
  amount.value = 0;
};
</script>
```

Bind name and amount with your inputs via v-model and bind addItem to your button with @click. You can use items as a prop for your ItemList component.

Your components need changes to work, but I hope this will give you some direction. Perhaps first make it work with plain html input and button elements and use `{{ items }}` to render the items array. Once that works you can create the custom components.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You gave me a direction, i should be able to go from there, we will see :D

Comment: Nice, good luck! :-)

Comment: I would advise to replace the 'ref' by other data properties so you can use the v-model to fill in that part. Also in the original code, addItem is used as v-model, which is not best practice.

@Floooorson, as you are learning Vue, Remember that there are better ways then using references. You should ALWAYS try to avoid that ;)

Comment: @Wimanicesir I think you are mixing up two kinds of ref. Using ref the way I show in my code example is the standard way to create reactive variables in the Vue Composition Api, [see docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#reactive-variables-with-ref). This is something different then [Template refs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html), which I also tend to avoid.